# Hive Alter table change Column Name

Tags: hive, alter-table, alter

I am trying to rename a columnName in Hive. Is there a way to rename column name in Hive .

tableA (column1 ,_c1,_c2) 
to 
tableA(column1,column2,column3)
??

Answer (score 99, accepted):

[Change Column Name/Type/Position/Comment](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ChangeColumnName/Type/Position/Comment):

> `ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE [COLUMN] col_old_name col_new_name column_type [COMMENT col_comment] [FIRST|AFTER column_name]`

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE test_change (a int, b int, c int);

// will change column a's name to a1
ALTER TABLE test_change CHANGE a a1 INT;
```

Comment: when renaming column names which were automatically generated from the query, such as the _c1, _c1 from OP, you will have to enclose the name with backticks

Comment: Thanks, this comment is very useful. I looked many places for this solution and could not find it. For what is a back tick - http://askubuntu.com/questions/20034/differences-between-doublequotes-singlequotes-and-backticks-%C2%B4-%C2%B4-on-comm

Comment: thanks to libjack. brackets don't work for me, but ` do.

Comment: Note that the column change will not change any underlying data if it is a parquet table. That is, if you have data in the table already, renaming a column will not make the data in that column accessible under the new name: 
select a from test_change; 
1 
alter table test_change change a a1 int; 
select a1 from test_change; 
null

Comment: @mike_pdb: I'm not sure that is intended. I understand why it happens, and perhaps ORC has the same problem, but I'm not sure is 'by design'. Can you create a JIRA? https://issues.apache.org/jira

Comment: @mike_pdb found https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6938 which claims this is fixed in Hive 0.14. Which version did you test with?

Comment: @RemusRusanu i'm using cloudera enterprise  the hive version per their doc sheet is hive-1.1.0+cdh5.4.7+233.  i will try to test on ORC later today.

Answer (score 7):

Command works only if "use" -command has been first used to define the database where working in. Table column renaming syntax using DATABASE.TABLE throws error and does not work. Version: HIVE 0.12.

EXAMPLE:

```
hive> ALTER TABLE databasename.tablename CHANGE old_column_name new_column_name;

  MismatchedTokenException(49!=90)
        at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.recoverFromMismatchedToken(BaseRecognizer.java:617)
        at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(BaseRecognizer.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.alterStatementSuffixExchangePartition(HiveParser.java:11492)
        ...

hive> use databasename;

hive> ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE old_column_name new_column_name;

OK
```

Answer (score 6):

```
alter table table_name change old_col_name new_col_name new_col_type;
```

Here is the example

```
hive> alter table test change userVisit userVisit2 STRING;      
    OK
    Time taken: 0.26 seconds
    hive> describe test;                                      
    OK
    uservisit2              string                                      
    category                string                                      
    uuid                    string                                      
    Time taken: 0.213 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the comments @libjack mentioned a point which is really important. I would like to illustrate more into it. First, we can check what are the columns of our table by `describe <table_name>;` command. [image]

there is a double-column called _c1 and such columns are created by the hive itself when we moving data from one table to another. To address these columns we need to write it inside backticks

```
`_c1`
```

Finally, the ALTER command will be,

```
ALTER TABLE <table_namr> CHANGE `<system_genarated_column_name>` <new_column_name> <data_type>;
```