# Aws Athena - Rename column name

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, ddl, amazon-athena

I am trying to change a column name in an AWS Athena table.
From `old_name` to `new_name`.

Normal DDL commands does not affect the table (They cannot be executed).

Is It possible to change a column name without deleting and re-creating the table from scratch ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was mistaken, Athena uses `HIVE DDL` syntax so the correct command is :
`ALTER TABLE %%table-name%% CHANGE %%old-column-name%% %%new-column-name%%<string>;`

I based my answer on a `hive` related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22041647/5052652).

Comment: Could you add a concrete example with multiple columns, please?

Answer (score 2):

You can find more about supported and unsupported DDLs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/language-reference.html)